# PhoneGap Login Form Redirect

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, cordova, mysqli

I am building a PhoneGap application using jquery mobile, PHP and MySQL. It will require an user authentication. I know that the file index.html will be hit as soon as the app is called like any other application for web. My question is: How do I force my app to go first to the login.html instead going to index.html and then, depending of the user entry, it will guide the user to index.html or not.
I know how to do for computer application but for this case the index.html should be the login page or is there any other way to work out this redirection ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mainpage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
    var user = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    if (user == null) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#loginpage');
    }
});

$('#loginpage').on('pageshow', function(event) {

    var user = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    if (user != null) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#mainpage');
    }
});
```

And if login success `localStorage.setItem('userInfo', ...);` then `$.mobile.changePage('#mainpage');`

Answer (score 0):

you will have to check if user is logged in or not in javascript on index.html if he is not then redirect to login.html else execute the code

Answer (score 0):

Check LocalStorage (Or whatever mechanism you're using to determine if a user is logged in) on index.html using javascript of course, and if they're not logged in, use basic javascript to redirect the user to the login page:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

There's plenty of documentation on the PhoneGap website about LocalStorage if you're using that mechanism.

Fun fact: PhoneGap doesn't support PHP.  It does however support making an ajax call to a PHP page on a server.

Comment: This works! Also I could see that $.mobile.changePage("main.html") also works fine. Thanks.

Comment: "Accept" the answer if it suffices.

Comment: I've tried to use this way but the better way was using $.mobile.changePage("main.html");